# Add getElementById with several IDs in the For loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

It is possible to add getElementById with several IDs in the For loop?
But first you have the querySelectorAll to list the IDs that have appeared.

Function that will return the formatted information if it exists:

```
function show_info(real_info, otp_inf) {
    if(real_info.indexOf('already exists') > -1) {
        var sinf = real_info.split("File '"+dir_files).pop();
        var sinf = sinf.split(' Overwrite').shift();
        $('#otp_'+otp_inf).html('<br><i><b class="rev-dev" style="font-size:14px">Not Encoded</b><br /><b>File \''+ sinf +'</b></i>');
    }
}
```

Here is the problem the For loop does not work if I put the getElementById inside:

```
var allids = document.querySelectorAll("#all_log div"); // To list all the IDs that have appeared
for (var i = 0; i < allids.length; i++) {
    if(allids[i].id.indexOf('bd_') > -1) { // Filter all IDs that start with...
        var idinfo = allids[i].id.split('bd_').pop(); // Show only the unknown name of the ID that will show the final text ......
        var id_info = document.getElementById(allids[i].id); // this line is not working
        show_info(id_info, idinfo);
    }
}
```

This will be the IDs:

```
<div id="all_log">
    <?php
        echo '<div class="hide_log" id="bd_'.md5(current($files)).'">'; //ID with the original text
        execOutput($cmd);
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div id="otp_'.md5(current($files)).'"></div>'; //ID with part of text
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: @aaron thx for the attention. I was adding the wrong cmd on the line: var id_info = `document.getElementById(allids[i].id);` correct is `var id_info = $('#'+allids[i].id).html();`

Comment: Well, that's not even close to what you were doing. Is this resolved then?

Comment: @aaron Yes, there were days I was in it just for having add a wrong cmd.

Comment: @aaron [Exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/jmsmarcelo/kkk2tknr/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the line, the goal is to collect the text in html of the ID, so it went wrong:

```
var id_info = document.getElementById(allids[i].id); // wrong

var id_info = $('#'+allids[i].id).html(); //correct
```